# Read snort.u2 files

Tags: linux, snort

I am just getting started with learning and testing snort.

I have some snort data in snort.u2.*timestamp* files. What is the best way to view / read these files? I have found some info via Google search but it discusses how to capture traffic using snort, parse it using barnyard2 and then load it into a mysql database. I can't find anything clear on how to read existing snort.u2 files. Also, I should mention that I have a barnyard2.waldo file along with the snort.u2.*timestamp* files. Not sure where this file comes in.

Also, is it possible to view snort.u2 files on Windows? It would be convient, but not a big deal if it is not possible.

Comment: Which stackexchange site would be better for this question? Is somebody able to migrate it to the appropriate site?

Answer (score 1):

Not really the best stackexchange site to ask that question, but `snort` comes with the `u2spewfoo` command for that:

```
u2spewfoo /path/to/file.unified2
```

See also the `u2boat` command to extract the `pcap`.

There is also a [SnortUnified module](http://code.google.com/p/snort-unified-perl/) for `perl` which can allow you to do fancier stuff with the unified2 log. A quick example to emulate u2spewfoo:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SnortUnified(qw(:ALL));
use Socket;
use POSIX;

$| = 1;
$file = shift;

$UF_Data = openSnortUnified($file) or die;

while ($record = readSnortUnifiedRecord()) {

  print(++$i);;

  foreach $field ( @{$record->{'FIELDS'}} ) {
    my $v = $record->{$field};
    if ($field =~ /^.ip$/) {
      $v = inet_ntoa(pack("N", $v));
    } elsif ( $field =~ /_sec$/) {
      $v = strftime("%F_%T", localtime $v);
    } elsif ( $field eq 'pkt' ) {
      $v = unpack("H*", $v);
    }
    print(", $field=" . $v);
  }
  print("\n");
}

closeSnortUnified();
```